# Как исправить внутренние неработающие ссылки?

Tags: wordpress

В Яндекс-вебмастере вижу внутренние неработающие ссылки:

1. "Ошибки на стороне сервера": [Откуда](https://baublys.ru/2018/05/17/cossa-ru-rasskazala-o-nas/) [Куда](https://baublys.ru/xmlrpc.php?rsd)
2. "Запрещены к индексированию или не существуют": [Откуда](https://baublys.ru/2019/11/29/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB/) [Куда](https://baublys.ru/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbaublys.ru%2F2019%2F11%2F29%2F%25d0%25bf%25d0%25be%25d0%25b8%25d1%2581%25d0%25ba-%25d0%25b2-%25d1%2582%25d0%25b0%25d0%25b1%25d0%25bb%25d0%25b8%25d1%2586%25d0%25b0%25d1%2585-%25d0%25b3%25d1%2583%25d0%25b3%25d0%25bb%2F&format=xml)

### **Объясните, пожалуйста, как исправить эти ошибки?**

Comment: Плагин Redirection подойдет?

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 2. Правило SO: один топик - один вопрос

Comment: @SeVlad сорри, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @Quazimorda стараюсь не умножать сущности без нужды. Без плагина никак?

Comment: @BorisBaublys понятней не стало. :( И что  - предлагаешь походить по ссылкам? Иначе зачем их подкладывать под анкоры. И причём тут яваскрипт и яндекс.. Не по ним же вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad Убрал 2 тега и 2 ссылки, без них понятнее суть проблемы?

Comment: @BorisBaublys Не умножая сущностей - курить мануалы на тему 301 редиректа и настраивать такие редиректы на сервере вручную в файле .htaccess. Или не мудрить и воспользоваться готовым решеним, то есть плагином ))

Comment: @BorisBaublys нет, не понятно. :(

Comment: @Quazimorda не зная ВП не надо давать дурацких советов и вообще лезть в метку ВП! Редиректы не только не нужны, но и могут поломать работу сайта.

Comment: @SeVlad Подскажете, как исправить вопрос?

Comment: @Quazimorda хочется понять причины появления этих ошибок, прежде чем делать что-то. У вас есть идеи на этот счёт?